# jQuery wait until element attribute has a value

Tags: jquery, wait

I have an element

```
<span id="current" data=""></span>
```

The value of the `data` attribute will be filled by an asynchronous AJAX function. I can't change this function to synchronous or have it return a value.

Here's part of the code

```
$("#popup #save").click(function () {

    //setting a lot of vars here

    var id = $("#current").val();

    if (id == '') {
        //new  so insert

        $.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            url: myurl,
            data: "",
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            dataType: "json",
            success: function (data) {
                $("#loadstatus").html('');
                //returns new id
                if (data > 0) {
                    $('#current').val(data);
                }
            }
        });
    }
    else {
        //existing  so update
        //more code
    }

    return false;

});



    var id = $("#current").val();
    if (id == '') {
        //save  
        $("#popup #save").click(); //this function contains the AJAX call which also sets `$("#current").val()` with a value returned in that same AJAX call

        //I can only set the value of id after the success of the aforementioned AJAX function
        //so here I need to set some sort of timeout
        id = $("#current").val();
    }
```

I want to execute another function, but within that function I want to wait until the attribute `data` is not equal to empty.
I was checking out this: http://javascriptisawesome.blogspot.com/2011/07/faster-than-jquerydocumentready-wait.html
But I prefer to do this with default jQuery.

How can I do so?

Comment: what are you using for your AJAX function?  Are you using $.post, $.get, or $.ajax?  Can you just call your second function from the success function of the AJAX call?

Comment: Why can't you change the function? Does it come from a library? What's the code?

Comment: It's a pretty long function, with a lot of variables being set and then a `$.ajax({
            type: "GET"` is executed.

Comment: I'd use the callback for ajax success; if you can't, then hook the change event on the span

Comment: Show the `$.ajax(...)` block in your question.

Answer (score 9):

You could poll for the value of data:

```
function check() {
    if (!$('#current').attr('data')) {
        return setTimeout(check, 1000);
    }

    // do work here
}

check();
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use a timeout to check periodically if the value is no longer empty.

http://jsfiddle.net/Delorian/1g932hj8/

Note 1: I changed your span to an imput to allow you update it in the JS Fiddle, but the code will work fine if it's a span.

Note 2: This is a recursive function, it calls itself to re-check the value after sleeping for 2 seconds. If you're implementing this, you should cater for running forever and cleaning up or stopping the call in certain circumstances.

```
var doSomethingOnceValueIsPresent = function () {
    if ($('#current').val() != '')
    {
        alert('something!');
    }
    else
    {
        setTimeout(function(){
            doSomethingOnceValueIsPresent()
            }, 2000);
    }
};

doSomethingOnceValueIsPresent();
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are able to change the `<span>` to an `<input>` you will be able to use jQuery's [`.change()`](http://api.jquery.com/change/) event which will make your life much easier.

```
<input id="current" value="" type="hidden" />
```

JS

```
$('#current').change(function(e){
    myFunction();
});
```